# Is it good practice to use Multiple Left Joins for fetching product details from different tables?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a select query as

```
    SELECT tbl_product.prod_id,tbl_product.manuf_id, tbl_product.cat_type_id, tbl_product.cat_id, tbl_product.prod_mpn, 
tbl_product.prod_name, tbl_product.prod_model, tbl_product.prod_retail_price, tbl_product.prod_purchase_price, tbl_product.prod_sp_offer_price, tbl_product.prod_stock_qty, tbl_product.prod_ships_in, 
tbl_product.prod_rating, tbl_product.prod_preorder, tbl_category_types.cat_type_name, tbl_category_types.cat_type_seo_name, tbl_category.cat_name, tbl_category.cat_seo_name, tbl_product_images.prod_image, tbl_product_details.prod_short_desc, tbl_product_details.prod_long_desc, tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_title, tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_keywords,tbl_product_details.prod_rel_keywords,tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_desc, tbl_product.network_id, tbl_network.network, tbl_network.network_seo_name, tbl_manufacturer.manuf_id, tbl_manufacturer.manuf_name, tbl_manufacturer.manuf_seo_name, tbl_product.prod_preorder_text
FROM tbl_product    
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_category_types ON tbl_category_types.cat_type_id = tbl_product.cat_type_id
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_category ON tbl_category.cat_id = tbl_product.cat_id
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_product_images ON tbl_product_images.prod_id = tbl_product.prod_id
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_product_details ON tbl_product_details.prod_id=tbl_product.prod_id                  
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_product_seo ON tbl_product_seo.prod_id = tbl_product.prod_id                    
        LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_network ON tbl_network.network_id = tbl_product.network_id
        LEFT JOIN
        tbl_manufacturer ON tbl_manufacturer.manuf_id = tbl_product.manuf_id                        
        WHERE 
        tbl_product.lang_id = '".$_SESSION["lang_id"]."' AND
        tbl_product.is_comp_phone = 0 AND 
        tbl_product.prod_id = '".$product_id."' AND
        tbl_product_seo.lang_id = '".$_SESSION["lang_id"]."' AND 
        tbl_product_seo.dom_id = '".$_SESSION["domain_id"]."' AND 
        tbl_product_details.lang_id = '".$_SESSION["lang_id"]."' AND 
        tbl_product_details.dom_id = '".$_SESSION["domain_id"]."'  
        LIMIT 1";
```

I need to fetch the product details using this query, is this way is good to proceed with?
or any better option is possible?

Comment: Did you know that everything in a DBMS is a table or a view so the 'tbl_' prefix is pretty moot?  It does not relay any useful information and clutters the names.  Likewise, your SQL would be more readable with carefully chosen table aliases (short names) instead of the full names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, it's fine.

The only bad thing is that it's potentially vulnerable to SQL injection (if anyone can modify `lang_id` or `domain_id` in the session, they will!)

It is highly recommended that you use parametrised queries with [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo), for example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1','user', 'password'); //assuming mysql
$sql = "SELECT
    tbl_product.prod_id,
    tbl_product.manuf_id,
    tbl_product.cat_type_id,
    tbl_product.cat_id,
    tbl_product.prod_mpn,
    tbl_product.prod_name,
    tbl_product.prod_model,
    tbl_product.prod_retail_price,
    tbl_product.prod_purchase_price,
    tbl_product.prod_sp_offer_price,
    tbl_product.prod_stock_qty,
    tbl_product.prod_ships_in,
    tbl_product.prod_rating,
    tbl_product.prod_preorder,
    tbl_category_types.cat_type_name,
    tbl_category_types.cat_type_seo_name,
    tbl_category.cat_name,
    tbl_category.cat_seo_name,
    tbl_product_images.prod_image,
    tbl_product_details.prod_short_desc,
    tbl_product_details.prod_long_desc,
    tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_title,
    tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_keywords,
    tbl_product_details.prod_rel_keywords,
    tbl_product_seo.prod_seo_desc,
    tbl_product.network_id,
    tbl_network.network,
    tbl_network.network_seo_name,
    tbl_manufacturer.manuf_id,
    tbl_manufacturer.manuf_name,
    tbl_manufacturer.manuf_seo_name,
    tbl_product.prod_preorder_text
FROM tbl_product
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_category_types ON tbl_category_types.cat_type_id = tbl_product.cat_type_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_category ON tbl_category.cat_id = tbl_product.cat_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_product_images ON tbl_product_images.prod_id = tbl_product.prod_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_product_details ON tbl_product_details.prod_id=tbl_product.prod_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_product_seo ON tbl_product_seo.prod_id = tbl_product.prod_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_network ON tbl_network.network_id = tbl_product.network_id
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_manufacturer ON tbl_manufacturer.manuf_id = tbl_product.manuf_id
WHERE 
    tbl_product.lang_id = :langid AND
    tbl_product.is_comp_phone = 0 AND 
    tbl_product.prod_id = :productid AND
    tbl_product_seo.lang_id = :langid AND 
    tbl_product_seo.dom_id = :domainid AND 
    tbl_product_details.lang_id = :langid AND 
    tbl_product_details.dom_id = :domainid
LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql)
$stmt->prepare(':langid', $_SESSION["lang_id"]);
$stmt->prepare(':productid', $productid);
$stmt->prepare(':domainid', $_SESSION["domain_id");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row === false) {
        // no rows
    } else {
        //do something with row data
    }
}
```

I also cleaned it up a bit. I happen to like one line per column in a query, but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is OK. But please keep in mind that for MySQL LEFT JOINs are harder to optimize, so for performance sake use INNER JOINs where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a fine query to me.

Answer (score 0):

Bad query, you have converted some of those left joins to inner joins by using them in the where clause. You need to move the filtering conditions for tbl_product_seo and tbl_product_details to the ON clause of the left joins.

Answer (score 0):

As HLGEM says the left joins are pointless on some of those tables, as soon as you used them in the where clause the Optimizer will turn them into INNER JOINS.

Reason being is that you usually use a LEFT JOIN to get records in one table and any records if they exist in a second table, this will bring back NULLS where no record exists in the second table.

With using a WHERE clause to restrict items in the second table, it can never return NULLS, therefore a LEFT JOINS is utterly pointless